# Create a kiosk with tmux

Tags: tmux, kiosk

How can I configure tmux such that the user in a session can not do anything other than interact with the programs in it and detach from the session?

I've bound a key to detach, but need a way to disable the prefix key in order to prevent the user from opening new windows/panes/sessions/shells.